# UICollectionView not load new data when make another API Calls Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uicollectionview

Here I'm trying to load the collectionView with another data that fetch from API Calls. At first, I call the data load into CollectionView and it works but when scroll until the bottom I call a method in scrollview to fetch more data, the data is return but the collection view is not updating. I have a struct that manage API calls and it will pass to another VC via delegate and append it into array.

**What did I expect**

- Another data that get from API calls will load into collectionView

**What did actually happend**

- Data only able to load at the first call and when try to fetch another call, collectionView do not update and keep refresh the first data that get from earlier API calls

**Here's my class that manage networking**

**NewsManager.swift**

```
import UIKit

protocol NewsManagerDelegate {
    func didSendNewsData (_ newsManager: NewsManager, with news : [NewsModel])
}


struct NewsManager {
    
    var delegate : NewsManagerDelegate?

    let newsUrl = "https://gnews.io/api/v4/search?q="
    let key = "APIKEY"
    
    func fetchNews(topics : String = "Apple",page:Int = 1){
        let urlString = "\(newsUrl)\(topics)&lang=en&page=\(page)&token=\(key)"
        print(urlString)
        performRequest(with : urlString)
    }

    
    func performRequest(with urlString : String){
        
        
        // 1. create URL object
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {fatalError("There's problem to fetch data from this url")}
        
        // 2. create session, object to do networking
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        //3. give session a task
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if error != nil{
                print("Error in giving session a task \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                
            } else{
                // determine if data is exist
                if let safeData = data {
                    //convert data to string
                    //let dataString = String(data: safeData, encoding: .utf8)
                    //print(dataString)
                    
                    // Parse the data here
                    guard let news = parseJSON(safeData) else{ fatalError("Error parsing data from JSON")}
                   
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        delegate?.didSendNewsData(self, with: news)
                    
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        //start the task
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func parseJSON(_ newsData : Data) -> [NewsModel]?{
        
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

        var newsModel = [NewsModel]()
        
        do{
    
            
            let decodeData = try decoder.decode(NewsData.self, from: newsData)
         
            
            print(decodeData.articles.count)
            
            for article in decodeData.articles {
                
            
                let newsTitle = article.title
                let newsDesc = article.description
                let newsURL = article.url
                let urlToImage = article.image
                let publishedAt = article.publishedAt
                let newsSource = article.source.name
                
                    let data = NewsModel(title: newsTitle, decription: newsDesc, url: newsURL, image: urlToImage, publishedAt: publishedAt, sourcesName: newsSource)
                    
                        newsModel.append(data)

            }
            
            return newsModel
            
        } catch{
            print("Error decode the data : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    
        }

        return newsModel
    }
}
```

****ViewController that will populate the data**

**NewsCollectionVC.swift****

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class NewsCollectionVC: UIViewController {
    

    
    var newsManager = NewsManager()
    var newsResults = [NewsModel]()
    
    let iso8601Formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    
    var dateFormatter : DateFormatter = {
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var pageNumber = 1
    var fetchMoreNews = false
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureVC()
    }
    
    func configureVC(){
        
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        
        newsManager.delegate = self
        newsManager.fetchNews()
    }
    
}


extension NewsCollectionVC : UICollectionViewDataSource{
    
    
    // Tell delegate how many cv need to show
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return 2
        return newsResults.count
    }
    
    // Tell delegate content of cv
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let listOfNews = newsResults[indexPath.row]
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CViewCell
        
        cell.title.text = listOfNews.title
        cell.desc.text = listOfNews.decription
        cell.source.text = listOfNews.sourcesName
        
        // Convert damn ISO8601 to other format, https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660878
        if let date = iso8601Formatter.date(from: listOfNews.publishedAt){
            let formattedString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
            cell.date.text = formattedString
        }
        
        cell.newsImage.downloaded(from: listOfNews.image)
        cell.newsImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        
        return cell
    }
    
}

extension NewsCollectionVC : UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    
    // Function to fetch more news
    func fetchOtherNews(){
        
        fetchMoreNews = true
        print("Begin Fetch More News")
        
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
            
            print("Page number : \(self.pageNumber) | newResults : \(self.newsResults.count)")
            self.fetchMoreNews = false
            self.newsManager.fetchNews(page: self.pageNumber)
            
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    
    // Tell delegate when user start scroll
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        let offSetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
        
        if offSetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.height * 1 {
            
            if !fetchMoreNews{
                pageNumber += 1
                fetchOtherNews()
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedNews = newsResults[indexPath.row]
        // Provide VC to run url in app
        let SafariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: selectedNews.url)
        // Present the app
        present(SafariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
}


extension NewsCollectionVC : NewsManagerDelegate {
    
    func didSendNewsData(_ newsManager: NewsManager, with news: [NewsModel]) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            
            self.newsResults.append(contentsOf: news)
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            print("Current Page Number : \(self.pageNumber) | News Result :\(self.newsResults.count)")
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see "Current Page Number" printed to the console from your `didSendNewsData()` method?

Comment: Yup I can see, it return **Current Page Number : 4 | News Result :20**

Comment: You are reloading the collection view in numerous places. You should only update the collection view in one place; the delegate method where you receive the additional data. Don't reload. Append the new items to the collection view. If you reload then the whole collection view is redrawn

Comment: @Paulw11 alright I have removed some reload methods and only put in the delegate in NewsCollectionVC, but the data is still not loaded and the console still print new value is already been loaded.

Comment: You missed the important part of my comment **Don't reload at all** (Except for the initial fetch) - You need to just add the new items to the collection view

Comment: Yup, I just put the reload method only at the initial fetch which will receive the data via delegate @Paulw11

Comment: You should only reload when you get the first set of items, not every time in the delegate.  You need to add code to call `insertItems(atIndexPaths:)` when you get the new items subsequently